# FATAL EXCEPTION: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.activation.DataHandler

Tags: android, email, noclassdeffounderror, activation, datahandler

I am building an email sending application for android OS. I have three jars: activation.jar, additional.jar, and mail.jar in my libs folder. I also have these three jar's included in the projects' build path, as "Referenced Libraries". When I run this application and try to send the mail, I got following error on LogCat.

> *FATAL EXCEPTION: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.activation.DataHandler*

I am totally stumped because many others are having the same NoClassDefFoundError error. Since I have the required jar libraries included in my class build path, I think it can be runtime error as described in the link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34419/3576562
Note: I followed this android email tutorial: http://www.chengxuyuans.com/qa/android/85326.html

**Activity.java:**

```
Button dialogButton1 = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.SendButton);
                dialogButton1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Forgot-Password-Request button", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        final EditText email = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.EditEmail);
                        if(email.getText() != null && email.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0){//check for email written. 
                            Runnable run = new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    SendPasswordRequestEmail(email.getText().toString());
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            };
                            (new Thread(run)).start();

                        }
                    }
                });

public void SendPasswordRequestEmail(String emailAddress){
        try{
            GMailSender sender = new GMailSender("nsdonaldwebmail@gmail.com", "email password");
            sender.sendMail("This is Subject",   
                    "This is Body",   
                    "nsdonaldwebmail@gmail.com",   
                    "nsdonaldwebmail@gmail.com"); 
        }catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("MailChimp", "SendEmail Method-Exception forgot password email: " + ex.getMessage());
            showResult("SendEmail Method-Exception forgot password email: "+ex.getMessage(), "Error");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**GMailSender.java:**

```
package com.example.proactiveregistrationapplication;
import javax.activation.DataHandler;   
import javax.activation.DataSource;   
import javax.mail.Message;   
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;   
import javax.mail.Session;   
import javax.mail.Transport;   
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;   
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;   
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;   
import java.io.IOException;   
import java.io.InputStream;   
import java.io.OutputStream;   
import java.security.Security;   
import java.util.Properties;   

public class GMailSender extends javax.mail.Authenticator {   
    private String mailhost = "smtp.gmail.com";   
    private String user;   
    private String password;   
    private Session session;   

    static {   
        Security.addProvider(new com.example.proactiveregistrationapplication.JSSEProvider());   
    }  

    public GMailSender(String user, String password) {   
        this.user = user;   
        this.password = password;   

        Properties props = new Properties();   
        props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");   
        props.setProperty("mail.host", mailhost);   
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");   
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");   
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");   
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",   
                "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");   
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");   
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");   

        session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, this);   
    }   

    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {   
        return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);   
    }   

    public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body, String sender, String recipients) throws Exception {   
        try{
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);   
        DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(body.getBytes(), "text/plain"));   
        message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));   
        message.setSubject(subject);   
        message.setDataHandler(handler);   
        if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0)   
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipients));   
        else  
            message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients));   
        Transport.send(message);   
        }catch(Exception e){

        }
    }   

    public class ByteArrayDataSource implements DataSource {   
        private byte[] data;   
        private String type;   

        public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data, String type) {   
            super();   
            this.data = data;   
            this.type = type;   
        }   

        public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data) {   
            super();   
            this.data = data;   
        }   

        public void setType(String type) {   
            this.type = type;   
        }   

        public String getContentType() {   
            if (type == null)   
                return "application/octet-stream";   
            else  
                return type;   
        }   

        public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {   
            return new ByteArrayInputStream(data);   
        }   

        public String getName() {   
            return "ByteArrayDataSource";   
        }   

        public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {   
            throw new IOException("Not Supported");   
        }   
    }   
}
```

**JSSEProvider.java:**

```
package com.example.proactiveregistrationapplication;

import java.security.AccessController;
import java.security.Provider;

public final class JSSEProvider extends Provider {

    public JSSEProvider() {
        super("HarmonyJSSE", 1.0, "Harmony JSSE Provider");
        AccessController.doPrivileged(new java.security.PrivilegedAction<Void>() {
            public Void run() {
                put("SSLContext.TLS",
                        "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.SSLContextImpl");
                put("Alg.Alias.SSLContext.TLSv1", "TLS");
                put("KeyManagerFactory.X509",
                        "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.KeyManagerFactoryImpl");
                put("TrustManagerFactory.X509",
                        "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerFactoryImpl");
                return null;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Logcat Errors:

```
04-17 16:15:04.395: I/art(26895): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<javax.activation.DataHandler>
04-17 16:15:04.395: I/art(26895): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<javax.activation.DataHandler>
04-17 16:15:04.415: W/(26895): Unable to open '/system/framework/com.qti.location.sdk.jar': No such file or directory
04-17 16:15:04.415: W/art(26895): Failed to open zip archive '/system/framework/com.qti.location.sdk.jar': I/O Error
04-17 16:15:04.435: W/(26895): Unable to open '/system/framework/com.qti.location.sdk.jar': No such file or directory
04-17 16:15:04.435: W/art(26895): Failed to open zip archive '/system/framework/com.qti.location.sdk.jar': I/O Error
04-17 16:15:04.435: W/(26895): Unable to open '/system/framework/com.qti.location.sdk.jar': No such file or directory
04-17 16:15:04.435: W/art(26895): Failed to open zip archive '/system/framework/com.qti.location.sdk.jar': I/O Error
04-17 16:15:04.445: W/(26895): Unable to open '/system/framework/com.qti.location.sdk.jar': No such file or directory
04-17 16:15:04.445: W/art(26895): Failed to open zip archive '/system/framework/com.qti.location.sdk.jar': I/O Error
04-17 16:15:04.455: W/(26895): Unable to open '/system/framework/com.qti.location.sdk.jar': No such file or directory
04-17 16:15:04.455: W/art(26895): Failed to open zip archive '/system/framework/com.qti.location.sdk.jar': I/O Error
04-17 16:15:04.455: W/(26895): Unable to open '/system/framework/com.qti.location.sdk.jar': No such file or directory
04-17 16:15:04.455: W/art(26895): Failed to open zip archive '/system/framework/com.qti.location.sdk.jar': I/O Error
04-17 16:15:04.465: I/art(26895): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<javax.activation.DataHandler>
04-17 16:15:04.465: I/art(26895): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<javax.activation.DataHandler>
04-17 16:15:04.465: I/art(26895): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<javax.activation.DataHandler>
04-17 16:15:04.465: I/art(26895): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<javax.activation.DataHandler>
04-17 16:15:04.465: I/art(26895): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<javax.activation.DataHandler>
04-17 16:15:04.465: I/art(26895): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<javax.activation.DataHandler>
04-17 16:15:04.465: I/art(26895): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<javax.activation.DataHandler>
04-17 16:15:04.465: I/art(26895): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<javax.activation.DataHandler>
04-17 16:15:04.475: I/art(26895): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<javax.activation.DataHandler>
04-17 16:15:04.475: I/art(26895): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<javax.activation.DataHandler>
04-17 16:15:04.475: I/art(26895): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<javax.activation.DataHandler>
04-17 16:15:04.475: I/art(26895): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<javax.activation.DataHandler>
04-17 16:15:04.475: I/art(26895): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<javax.activation.DataHandler>
04-17 16:15:04.485: I/art(26895): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<javax.activation.DataHandler>
04-17 16:15:04.485: E/AndroidRuntime(26895): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-6719
04-17 16:15:04.485: E/AndroidRuntime(26895): Process: com.example.proactiveregistrationapplication, PID: 26895
04-17 16:15:04.485: E/AndroidRuntime(26895): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.activation.DataHandler
04-17 16:15:04.485: E/AndroidRuntime(26895):    at com.example.proactiveregistrationapplication.GMailSender.sendMail(GMailSender.java:52)
04-17 16:15:04.485: E/AndroidRuntime(26895):    at com.example.proactiveregistrationapplication.UnsubscribeActivity.SendPasswordRequestEmail(UnsubscribeActivity.java:216)
04-17 16:15:04.485: E/AndroidRuntime(26895):    at com.example.proactiveregistrationapplication.UnsubscribeActivity$3$1$1.run(UnsubscribeActivity.java:83)
04-17 16:15:04.485: E/AndroidRuntime(26895):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
04-17 16:15:04.635: D/ViewRootImpl(26895): MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 759) or=1
04-17 16:15:04.655: I/Timeline(26895): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@7b3d479 time:49039028
04-17 16:15:04.945: D/ViewRootImpl(26895): #3 mView = null
04-17 16:15:04.965: E/WindowManager(26895): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.proactiveregistrationapplication.UnsubscribeActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{4f688cf V.E...... R......D 0,0-1002,565} that was originally added here
04-17 16:15:04.965: E/WindowManager(26895):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:565)
04-17 16:15:04.965: E/WindowManager(26895):     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:326)
04-17 16:15:04.965: E/WindowManager(26895):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
04-17 16:15:04.965: E/WindowManager(26895):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:350)
04-17 16:15:04.965: E/WindowManager(26895):     at com.example.proactiveregistrationapplication.UnsubscribeActivity$3.onClick(UnsubscribeActivity.java:99)
04-17 16:15:04.965: E/WindowManager(26895):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5697)
04-17 16:15:04.965: E/WindowManager(26895):     at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10826)
04-17 16:15:04.965: E/WindowManager(26895):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22526)
04-17 16:15:04.965: E/WindowManager(26895):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
04-17 16:15:04.965: E/WindowManager(26895):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-17 16:15:04.965: E/WindowManager(26895):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
04-17 16:15:04.965: E/WindowManager(26895):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
04-17 16:15:04.965: E/WindowManager(26895):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
04-17 16:15:04.965: E/WindowManager(26895):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
04-17 16:15:04.965: E/WindowManager(26895):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Answer (score 0):

Cause: Exact cause is unknown to me. I think that it could have been a configuration error in the runtime classpath, found at project->(Right-click)->Run as->Run Configurations, also noted in https://stackoverflow.com/a/34419/3576562.

Extra Effort that I tried: In the "Run Configurations" window, I made sure the **name of my project** matches the name of the project under the "**Android Application**" tab and **Android->Project:** tab. Note: this did not fix my NoClassDefFoundError error, also initially in my project there was a mismatch in the names for the "Run Configurations" window.

Alternative solution to this "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.activation.DataHandler" run-time error was to **create a new android project** and copy all contents from the original project including the original source code and android manifest.

I also used Alternative Email solution;

- Email Project: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UNPFWCNMJPU
- Source Code: http://www.indragni.com/android/SendEmail.rar <<- includes activation.jar. additionnal.jar, and mail.jar libraries